# New database or index key for each client?

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012

We are currently building a web application using ASP.net and Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
Each of our customer will have the ability to add other customers below them.

Our Company
--> Our Customers
    ---> Customer's Customers

Is it preferable to create a new database for each of our customer or just use a seperate table and automatically apply key filter in their GUI?

Comment: See [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33782/one-database-per-company-for-security-reasons) on the DBA site

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described (briefly) I would not suggest having a separate DB for each client.  If each client was getting their own application/website, then yes, you may then want to have each client have their own instance of a DB (as well as application, server, etc).  In this case, it seems that each client will need to interact with one another.  Difficult to do if they are located in various databases. Instead, look to creating a normalized database schema that uses a recursive table for customers.  You can create a schema similar to something like this:

**tblOurCompany**

companyId(pk int)

companyName(varchar)
....

**tblOurCustomers**

custId(pk int)

custName(varChar)

custParent(int)

**tblCompany_Customer**

companyId(pk)

customerId(pk)

This quick mock up is a table that has a Company table (assuming you have multiple companies or maybe this might be business units) and a customers table.  Because you may have multiple companies with multiple customers, you need to have a table that unifies them both, the company_customers table.  The crux of this design, though, is the recursive design of the customers table.  Each table would have a customerID, which is the primary key, and a parent ID.  The parent ID is just the pk of another customer that is found in the customer table ( the root parent could have a value of 0).  For example:

```
companyId | companyName  | ParentId
-----------------------------------
1             CompanyA     0
2             CompanyB     0
3             CompanyC     1
4             CompanyD     1
5             CompanyE     4
```

This example has 5 companies.  Two are root companies (CompanyA/B).  CompanyA has two children (C and D).  CompanyE has one child, CompanyD.

It is important to understand database normalization.  If you were to follow your first inclination to use a different DB for each customer, you would be spending a great deal more money (db licenses cost money + server costs + space, etc) and causing unnecessary difficulty when it comes to getting your data and working with it using SQL and whatever applications may be using it.  Heres a quick intro to normalization:  http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

If you have any other questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on expected scale. If you expect that "Our Customers" will be ten, then separate databases may work fine, but understand that there is added administration cost for multiple databases.

But what if "Our Customers" will be 100 or 1,000 long-term. Do you want to manage 1,000 individual databases?

A good reference here is Microsoft's [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).

My personal recommendation (based on experience with two production SaaS systems) is to have a single database and a single table.

Customer Table (think of this as Tenant):

- PK: TenantID

Customer's (Tenant's) Customer Table:

- PK: TenantID, CustomerID
- FK: TenantID